# Adding multiple rows with common Name

Tags: excel

I have a report of 600 customers.
 Some customers name are same but they are not sorted in the alphabetical order. Sometimes the name of the borrower appears 1 time 2 or more times.

I need to add the numbers which are associated to that borrower. So that excel read all the names which are identical and then sum those rows only. See example below:

```
Company Name        Dollar     Sum      My desired result
Argentina           $2          $14
Argentina           $3          $14
Italy               $60         $60
Argentina           $4          $14
Argentina           $5          $14
Brazil              $10         $30
Brazil              $20         $30
```

What formula can I put in SUM Column so that excel makes a search of identical names of the country and then add their corresponding $ to the sum column?
I have also shown a column which shows my desired result. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would us SUMIFS():

```
=SUMIF(A:A,A2,B:B)
```

in C2 and copy down